# Unable to see the data in child component

Tags: reactjs

hi i am trying to send from parent to child....but i can see the child component all data of child...i do not want see that...can one help on this....i do not want all child component data in parent component

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Child from "./child";

export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>This is parent</h2>
        <div>
          <Child name="Robert" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

child.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>This is {this.props.name} </h2>
        <div>Child 1</div>
        <div>Child 2</div>
        <div>Child 3</div>
        <div>Child 4</div>
        <div>Child 5</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more what you want to achieve ? I did not understand

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-yonath-1e191?file=/src/components/parent.js.....please this link....in the app.js i can see the child data...i dont want to see

Comment: You mean deleting the `<div>Child {x}</div>` tags ?

Comment: not to delete....i just want show one line of div...can we do like that

Comment: Well, this is a css matter and have a lot of solutions

Comment: if i do like that...if i enter into child component i cannot see the data....in the web

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions and our comments, you need to display the parent's children in the same line. You can do something like this:

```
<div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
  <div>Child 1</div>
  <div>Child 2</div>
  <div>Child 3</div>
  <div>Child 4</div>
  <div>Child 5</div>
</div>
```

See [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-goldberg-od0hg)

Comment: no i do not want see in one line....i am using props here to get that child data to parent component...i can see child1, child2..etc....i do not want to see the other child div's

Comment: sorry bro...i do not want delete....child component data....just i want show child 1 div only into parent...can we do like that